# Processing Office & PDF files C#

Tags: image-processing, document-converter

I have a very specific requirement want to convert Word, Excel, PowerPoint, text and PDF files to images. There is a bulk load of 3rd party tools available to do that like: (if I have missed a tool please feel free to add)

1. [Aspose](https://purchase.aspose.com/pricing/total/net)
2. [devexpress](https://www.devexpress.com/buy/NET/)
3. [syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/xlsio)
4. [telerik](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/document-processing/introduction)
5. [prizmdoc](https://www.accusoft.com/products/prizmdoc/pricing/)
6. [x-doc](http://www.rasteredge.com/xdoc/converter/pricing/)

My problem is all of these are expensive, their prices are justified if I am going to use all features. So can you guys help identify any other product or solution that I can use free or paid (under $1000).

Comment: It would be a good idea to specify which types of Word, Excel & Power Point files - i.e. .doc or .docx? how about .docxm? PowerPoint or PowerPoint SlideShow ppt/pps/pptx/ppsx? Which Image format(s) - for multipage documents just the first page, all pages in a gif/tiff or one image per page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Syncfusion File Formats](https://www.syncfusion.com/sales/products/fileformats) edition is $995 (meets the requirement of being under $1000) and can convert Word, Excel, PowerPoint (PPTX) and PDF to images. Text can also be converted by inserting into a word document using the API.

The whole product is also available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Disclaimer: I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use LibreOffice in headerless mode to load the files and convert to images. This can be done with scripting (in python).

One of the possibilities within this is to install a PDF Printer Driver and then use the headerless mode to print the files, (other than the PDFs) to PDF format and then use ImageMagick to convert all of the PDFs to image sets.

Comment: I tried this but it only converts first page of any document (pdf|pptx|docx|doc|ppt)  soffice --headless --convert-to png --outdir "path\to\out" "path\to\out\Test.docx"

Comment: Can you code Python?

Comment: I don't code python but will do it if it solves my problem.